# How do I make sure the gutenberg block CSS is not disrupted by generic styles?

Tags: block-editor, css

I am working with a pre-existing theme. On the site in question, the style sets rules for P tags. These rules are applied in preference to the class styles for P tags used in certain blocks. (With the result that covers, for example, look quite silly). How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean covers? can you share your URL so we can see what is "silly" and what should you do.

Comment: Covers are a built-in block type. By silly, I mean that style.css defines `p` as something like `12pt` which makes `.has_huge_font_size` overridden.

Comment: There's nothing special about Gutenberg here, your CSS just needs to use [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) appropriately.

Comment: Is there some way I can restate the block CSS, queue it last, or make it all !important? The theme is nice but it does not play well with the new block approached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the default blocks add a class `wp-block-[name]` to the block's root element on save. You could use these to increase your class specificity.

For your example of covers, `.wp-block-cover .has-huge-font-size` or `.wp-block-cover p.has-huge-font-size` depending on how much specificity you need.